# AngularFire get the latest evaluated $value from Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I need some help to get the latest evaluated $value from Firebase in angularjs. I'm only able to get the returned value '1' which is different than the expected $value after having been evaluated. Somehow the $value in html is reflecting the expected value.

Firebase DB

```
-- TraineeCounter: 28
```

Here is my firebase factory:

```
    /// * found that this factory caused the issue of value returns 1
function TraineesCounter($firebaseObject) {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("TraineeCounter");
    ref.transaction(function(currentValue) {
        return (currentValue || 0) + 1;
    });

    return $firebaseObject(ref);
}

// defined wif pad trainees counts factory
function TraineesCount($firebaseObject){
    var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("TraineeCounter");
        // return it as a synchronized object
    return $firebaseObject(ref);
}
```

Then, I injected it into a controller as below:

```
$scope.TraineesCounter = TraineesCounter;
$scope.traineeCount = TraineesCount;

$scope.traineeCount.$loaded().then(function(data) {
    console.log("$loaded data", data);
    console.log("$loaded value", data.$value);
});
```

Console display:

```
$loaded data 
  e {$$conf: Object, $id: "wifPadTraineeCounter", $priority: null, $value: 1}
  $$conf: Object
  $id: "wifPadTraineeCounter"
  $priority: null
  $value: 28
  __proto__: Object

$loaded value 1
```

index.html:

```
    <pre>{{traineeCount | json}}</pre>
    <span>{{traineeCount.$value}}</span>
```

HTML output:

```
{
  "$id": "wifPadTraineeCounter",
  "$priority": null,
  "$value": 27
}
27
```

Comment: Try to console.log($scope.traineeCount) in callback. What is it?

Comment: `$scope.traineeCount.$loaded().then(function(data) {
   console.log("callback", $scope.traineeCount); // return 1
  });`

Comment: i added another service here, so you have a better picture. If removed the problematic service, the callback can return an expected value